# How would I make this program print the coded message?

Tags: java

How would i use this code below print out a decoded word by only using the what the user enters as the coded word and a pattern. So far I was able to make the program set up all the varibles I just do not understand how I would subtract after each letter the pattern amount and put that into a coded word

here is what i have so far

```
import java.util.*;

public class happy{

public static void main (String [] args){ 

      Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in); //imports scanner reader

System.out.println("\nplease enter a code to decrypt");
    String userinput0 = inputScanner.next(); //assigns the word entered by user to varible userinput
    System.out.println("please enter the pattern for the decryption");
    String userinput1 = inputScanner.next(); //assigns the word entered by user to varible userinput
    int inputting2 = Integer.parseInt(userinput1); //changes the string value to integer value

   // for(int yt = 0; yt < yu; yt++){

     // System.out.print(charArray[yt]);

      for(int hh = 0; hh < inputting2; hh--){
System.out.println();

      } //end of for loop
   // } //end of for loop

}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a Vigenère Cipher?

Comment: um im not sure what that is but ill give you an example of how it is suppose to run:  
-say the code user enters is: HaEdLdLsOs
-and the pattern is 1
-the program should print out HELLO as the decoded message

Comment: so the program has to be able to find the random letters according to the pattern and delete them then print that word out

Comment: you mean taking away a character at position 1,3,5,7...etc? What if the pattern is 3?

Comment: if the pattern is 3 then there would be mroe random letters inbetween each letter example word is HELLO the coded word would be HedfEsdfLetrLdwrOers

Comment: I see..stay on, let me type my solutions... you want to decrypt and not encrypt right?

Comment: yes I created a encryption code let me know if that would help you solve my problem. thank you so much

Comment: Why is there userInput0 and userInput1 ?? Extra variable?

Comment: those are for what the user enters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this...this is for decryption.

`encryptedText` is the encrypted text to be decrypted and pattern is `int`

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in); //imports scanner reader

System.out.println("\nplease enter a code to decrypt");
String encryptedText = scn.nextLine(); //assigns the word entered by user to varible userinput
System.out.println("please enter the pattern for the decryption");
int pattern = scn.nextInt(); //changes the string value to integer value
scn.nextLine();

for (int x=0; x<encryptedText.length(); x+=(pattern+1))
    System.out.print(encryptedText.charAt(x));
```

Copy everything from here and replace everything in your main. It will work.
This is prompting user to enter the encrypted text. If you already have the encrypted text. You don't even need to prompt user anymore.

Just pass your encrypted text to variable `encryptedText`.

I tested it.. it is working..

**Program Output**

```
please enter a code to decrypt
a..p..p..l..e..i..s..g..o..o..d..
please enter the pattern for the decryption
2
appleisgood
```

Comment: ok but when i paste that in what do i set str and pattern to? they cannot be revolsved

Comment: My code works, but your original code needs some editing.. I will tell you what to edit in my reply..

Comment: what do i need to switch?

Comment: copy and paste everything again, I edited already..str should not be in there.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH!! I have been stuck on that for a while now thanks again

Comment: You are welcome, I love to help. I hate to downvote people. Cheers!